# The argument type 'MaterialColor' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Paint'

Tags: android, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

I want to set the background color red, but there is no **'backgroundColor'** property under **TextStyle** widget.

There is background property but i can't set the value for background. It shows error & the error is

> The argument type 'MaterialColor' can't be assigned to the parameter
>   type 'Paint'

**The error is reasonable, i know.** But what should be the value of background property ?

I search but unfortunately can't find :( 
I can set background as `background: Paint()` and the background goes to black. But i need red background. 
***What should be the value of background ?***

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply set `color` property of `Paint` to `Colors.red`

```
Text(
  "Hello",
  style: TextStyle(background: Paint()..color = Colors.red),
),
```

Comment: oh ! "Paint()..color = Colors.red" , its called cascade method. I just learn this new things. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `background` to define a color, I advise you to use directly the `backgroundColor` property like this:

```
   Text(
        'Wow',
        style: TextStyle(backgroundColor: Colors.red),
      ),
```